# ESRI Js api 4.2: FeatureLayer does not draw all features in extent

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm upgrading a web application from ESRI js 3.19 to 4.2, but I'm experiencing problems with my FeatureLayers.

The data is coming from an ArcGIS Server 10.3 and the following restrictions are in place:
- maxRecordCount: 1000
- maxScale: 50000

When I add the FeatureLayer to my Map-Object (into a MapView) a very few features are displayed at random locations on the map. The same layer with the same settings in v3.19 is working like a charm.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Hi i can reproduce this behavior in 4.12 :( mapimagelayer is drawn without Problems, featurelayer is only drawing some Features, regardless of the renderer.